# Read a local html table in Python Pandas as a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a local html file on my harddisk, that is actually an html table. I would like to import it into a dataframe, so I apply following code line:

```
file = 'ETF/file.html'
df = pd.read_html(file)
```

I get the following error: ImportError: lxml not found, please install it

I have imported the following libraries:

```
import os.path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import requests
```

Any suggestions how to solve the problem?

Comment: `lxml` needs to exist in your python environment. So `pip install lxml` in your command line. If you can't do that, you may need to contact your IT department.

Comment: Please post the entire error traceback. Also, try `pd.read_html(file, flavor="html5lib")`. This does not need `lxml` per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html).

Comment: Ty, meanwhile I've installed lxml, but the table is read as list and not as a datframe if I use df = pd.read_html(file)

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install lxml
```

This will install the python package for you to import!
https://lxml.de/installation.html

Comment: Ty the data could be read, but somehow i doesn't have a table structure

Comment: Ty, meanwhile I've installed lxml, but the table is read as list and not as a datframe if I use df = pd.read_html(file)